# Getting second item from a tag-pair list

Tags: tags, filtering

Have tag-pair (generated as part of output from external call to Amazon AWS Ecommerce API) that returns a list of languages - vis:

```
{Item_ItemAttributes_Languages}
   {Language_Name}
{/Item_ItemAttributes_Languages}
```

How do I get just the second item in the list?

Hopefully not too difficult to do - just baffled currently about how to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in EE you can use the offset parameter.

`offset="1"` would start the output on the second item in the loop and setting a limit parameter `limit="1"` would return only the second item.

However, I am unsure if it works with your tags above as they are tag pairs within the AWS products module.

If offset is unavailable as a parameter, you may need to look into setting a php array and then outputting the second item of the array.